# Java: How to know when JOptionPane has been closed by clicking the X?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
            int r = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                    myPanel, 
                    "Choose", 
                    JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
                    null, 
                    new String[]{}, // this is the array
                    "default");
```

How do you catch the event when the user has clicked the X to close the dialog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

> When one of the showXxxDialog methods returns an integer, the possible
>   values are:
>
> ```
> YES_OPTION
> NO_OPTION
> CANCEL_OPTION
> OK_OPTION
> CLOSED_OPTION
> ```

I believe you are looking for the `CLOSED_OPTION` one.